# Rotation of constituent cubes of a rubik's cube

Tags: animation, 3d, rotation, javafx-8

I made a Rubik's cube by arranging smaller cubes. Now I want to apply animations to it. For that I am choosing to use the Rotate class and set the angle of rotation and the axis of rotation,like this

```
ar[12].setRotationAxis(Rotate.X_AXIS);//The array elements refer to the small cubes which make up the Rubik's cube.These elements represent the left face.
        ar[13].setRotationAxis(Rotate.X_AXIS);
        ar[14].setRotationAxis(Rotate.X_AXIS);
        ar[15].setRotationAxis(Rotate.X_AXIS);
        Rotate rotation1 = new Rotate(90);
        rotation1.setAxis(Rotate.X_AXIS);
```

Then I am applying the rotations as an animation,like this

```
Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
                new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(2), new KeyValue(ar[12].rotateProperty(), 90)),
                new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(2), new KeyValue(ar[13].rotateProperty(), 90)),
                    new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(2), new KeyValue(ar[14].rotateProperty(), 90)),
                    new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(2), new KeyValue(ar[15].rotateProperty(),  90)));
             timeline.play();
```

But with this I get the result like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSHP8.png).
As I could understand,  I am getting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwUx6.png) for each single cube but what I require for each cube is that the cubes must rotate about their edges by 90 degrees. How can I achieve this? And also another problem is that after 1 mouse click even the animation doesn't occur again. How can I fix this ?

Comment: Have a look at this [post](http://jperedadnr.blogspot.com/2014/04/rubikfx-solving-rubiks-cube-with-javafx.html), it will show you a possible way of dealing with rotations and animations

Comment: Okay that is really helpful, and what can I do that my animation plays every time I click on the mouse ?

Comment: You have all the code [here](https://github.com/jperedadnr/RubikFX), have a look.

Comment: Can you please explain me the rotation and animation part in a bit detail, I am sorry I am a newbie and could not understand much of it. Being specific, " listen how the timeline internally interpolate it, making small rotations between angNew and angOld angles" what does this mean? And how you applied this with the `Affine` class?. And if possible  is there a simpler way of this that I can apply to my code?